# is new a BigDecimal from another bigDecimal.toString() always equals?

Tags: java

In Java, is new a BigDecimal from another bigDecimal.toString() always equals?
For example

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1.23");
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(a.toString());

    System.out.println(a.compareTo(b) == 0); // always true?
```

I know BigDecimal is immutable, but i want to know if there is any good way to `clone` a BigDecimal object?

Comment: not much likely, you could always go for a shallow copy though

Comment: @CrakC could you show a example for shallow copy?

Comment: _if there is any good way to clone a BigDecimal object_ Do you mean only **from its `toString()` representation**?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I found toString() may works, but there should be any other good way.

Comment: There's a copy constructor as well. Any of the `add(BigDecimal.ZERO)`, `multiply(BigDecimal.ONE)` should work as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks very much. `add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` , `multiply(BigDecimal.ONE)` is very good idea.

Comment: @andyf I don't think it is. I can't find any guarantee that a new object is returned.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis there isn't a copy constructor, i.e one that takes BigDecimal as an argument

Comment: @SleimanJneidi You're right. I was looking at one with `BigInteger`. Thanks.

Comment: @andyf I just checked, and `BigDecimal.ZERO.add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` does not return a new object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeah, it doesn't need one  because it is immutable

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks. Yes `BigDecimal.ZERO.add(BigDecimal.ZERO) ` does not return a new object. may be its because the result is BigDecimal.ZERO too. But as I try other NOT ZERO value return a new object.

Comment: @andyf I wouldn't rely on that. Looking at the source code it seems common values are cached. Also in a future version they could change it so that `add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` always just does `return this;`. I would stick to `new BigDecimal(bigDecimal.toString());`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Indeed. should use `new BigDecimal(bigDecimal.toString())` for safety coding. This problem may  similar to `Integer.valueOf(127) == Integer.valueOf(127)` but `Integer.valueOf(128) != Integer.valueOf(128)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes you can assume so. From the [`BigDecimal.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString--) docs

> If that string representation is converted back to a `BigDecimal`
>   using the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor, then the original value
>   will be recovered.

However you can safely share the same object because it is `immutable` and copying is not required

Answer (score 6):

Just a remark : BigDecimal is not final so it can be extended by a mutable class. Making a defensive copy can therefore be required in some use cases.

The BigDecimal.toString() method can be used :

> ```
>  * There is a one-to-one mapping between the distinguishable
>  * {@code BigDecimal} values and the result of this conversion.
>  * That is, every distinguishable {@code BigDecimal} value
>  * (unscaled value and scale) has a unique string representation
>  * as a result of using {@code toString}.  If that string
>  * representation is converted back to a {@code BigDecimal} using
>  * the {@link #BigDecimal(String)} constructor, then the original
>  * value will be recovered.
> ```

Here an example of code making a defensive copy of BigDecimal :

```
public static BigDecimal safeInstance(BigDecimal val) { 
    return val.getClass() == BigDecimal.class ? 
    val : new BigDecimal(val.toString()); 
}
```

But does it make sense ? If a class extends the BigDecimal class you cannot be sure it does not extend its toString() method without respecting the contract...

Probably it's better to invalidate any extension of BigDecimal :

```
public static BigDecimal safeInstance(BigDecimal val) { 
    if (val.getClass() != BigDecimal.class) {
        //TODO throw exception
    }
    return val; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One simple way would be to add ZERO

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1.23");
BigDecimal b = a.add(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

Comment: The `add` method will may be return the same object. There is no guarantee that the add method returns another object.

Comment: I've taken a look in BigDecimal.class and it seems to always return a new BigDecimal