# Is it legitimate to define final an immutable parameter, bind the parameter to another local variable and mutate the local variable?

Tags: java, clone, immutability, final

Note well: The same question applies for other immutable types, like String and Boolean.

---

I have a method like this (this is a simple example of a more complicated method):

#### Example 1

```
public BigDecimal addTwo(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(new BigDecimal(2));
    return bigDecimal;
}
```

I know, I could simply return `bigDecimal.add(new BigDecimal(2))`. But it's only an example.

The problem with this code is that I can't add `final` to the method parameter and Eclipse bothers me. So I would write:

#### Example 2

```
public BigDecimal addTwo(final BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimalLocal = bigDecimal;
    bigDecimalLocal = bigDecimalLocal.add(new BigDecimal(2));
    return bigDecimalLocal;
}
```

I know, I can do directly `BigDecimal bigDecimalLocal = bigDecimal.add(new BigDecimal(2))`. But I repeat, this is only an example.

The question is: when I do:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimalLocal = bigDecimal;
```

I'm ***not*** creating a new `BigDecimal`. I'm assigning the same object to a different variable. I [found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381260/is-new-a-bigdecimal-from-another-bigdecimal-tostring-always-equals) that a simple way to clone `BigDecimal` is:

#### Example 3

```
BigDecimal bigDecimalLocal = new BigDecimal(bigDecimal.toString());
```

The question is: since `BigDecimal` is immutable, is this really necessary? Can't I simple do as in example #2? I think the `final` keyword could not be invalidated in that way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193257/discussion-on-question-by-marco-sulla-is-it-lecit-to-define-final-an-immutable-p).

Comment: Regarding the title, by "lecit" do you mean permitted, allowed? If so, that should be "legitimate" (shortened form is "legit", but that's not a real word).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I admit my ignorance about the `final` keyword:

- If you reassign a parameter inside the method, `final` or not, the object remains unchanged, of course
- If you instead modify a non immutable object, `final` or not, the object changes also outside the method.
- It seems the only thing that a parameter with `final` do is that it can't be reassigned within the method only.

I must say I do something like this a lot of time:

```
public List<MyBean> findByNation(String nation) {
    if (nation != null) {
        nation = nation.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        nation = "";
    }
    
    [...]
}
```

or

```
public List<Date> findConfirmedDates(Date start, Date end) {
    if (end == null) {
        end = new Date();
    }
}
```

or

```
public String findFilteredSql(String queryFilter, SearchBean searchBean) {
    if (searchBean.getSupplierId() != null) {
        queryFilter += " JOIN SUPPLIER_COMMODITY sc ON sc.SUPPLIERID = v.SUPPLIERID ";
    }
    
    [...]
}
```

or

```
public static String format(BigDecimal val, Locale locale, int scale) {
    if (val == null) {
        return "-";
    }
    
    val = valLocal.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
    val = val.multiply(NumberUtility.BigDecimal100);
    
    [...]
}
```

IMHO it's much more readable the way I wrote the methods above, and sorry for `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Example 2 is fine, but you don't need local variables at all and I think they decrease the readability of the method. I would simply do

```
public BigDecimal addTwo(final BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    return bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2));
}
```

> What if I want to add another BigDecimal"? I have to return `bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(3))`? I think it's not so readable.

If you're going to add two many times (or multiple constants), then it might make sense to extract constants as constants. Like,

```
private static final BigDecimal TWO = BigDecimal.valueOf(2);
private static final BigDecimal THREE = BigDecimal.valueOf(3);

public static BigDecimal addTwoAndThree(final BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    return TWO.add(THREE).add(bigDecimal);
}
```

Comment: I wrote in the question that, and that this is just an example.

Comment: @MarcoSulla *I wrote in the question that,* My answer is worry more about code readability, which is not in your question.

Comment: What if I want to add another `BigDecimal`? I have to return `bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(3))`? I think it's not so readable.

Comment: @MarcoSulla `bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2)).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(3))`, which is as readable as it gets.

Comment: IMHO it's more readable `bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2); bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(3);` (imagine it with returns)

Comment: @MarcoSulla do you see the problem? "IMHO"..., Os everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't understand the concept of references.

When you have this:

```
BigDecimal incoming = new BigDecimal(2);
addTwo(incoming);
...

public BigDecimal addTwo(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
  bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(new BigDecimal(2));
}
```

Thing is: `incoming` is still **2** after that method ended!

That `add()` call creates a **new** BigDecimal object, and the variable bigDecimal points then to that new object.

But the reference `incoming` still points to the old object!

Long story short: that keyword final for method parameter does **not at all** what you think it does. Its sole purpose is to prevent you from re-assigning to that parameter/value. So you really want to learn about the difference between [objects and references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160485/object-vs-reference-in-java). And then about [pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: The problem is I ***can't*** add the `final` keyword in that way to the parameter of `addTwo()`. Or are you saying is useless to add it in this case?